# Determine whether this integral converges: $\int_1^\infty\frac{(x+1)\arctan x}{(2x+5)\sqrt x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Determine whether the next integral converges: $$\int_1^\infty\frac{(x+1)\arctan x}{(2x+5)\sqrt x}$$

I has this one on a test and lost all my points on this one. Since we were given no answers to the test I still have no idea how to solve it.

Can you please give me the idea on how to solve that one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
so
$$\frac{(x+1)\arctan x}{(22x+5)\sqrt x}\sim_\infty\frac{\pi}{44\sqrt{x}}$$
 and since the integral 
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$$ is divergent hence the  given integral is also divergent by limit comparaison.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would you give full points for this answer?

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope that the answer is now clear.

Comment: I feel pretty stupid. And i know it should be pretty easy using comparison tests (I actually wrote it does no converges, And used almost exactly what you wrote about).
But you have to prove it. What you wrote is correct after proving that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\epsilon R$?

Comment: I was just asking, I think it was fine the first time. I was even the one upvoter so far.

Comment: You should probably say "by *limit* comparison" for full marks from me.

Comment: @TedShifrin In french we use the term "par équivalence" i.e. by equivalence and I don't know if the traduction is correct and if it's used.

Comment: @Sami: Ça fait évidemment du sens :) C'est autre chose que la comparaison :) In English, the "limit comparison test" refers to asymptotic behavior, as opposed to strict comparison.

Comment: Just as a constructive criticism, I would have started with
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(x+1)\arctan(x)}{22x+5}=\frac\pi{44}
$$
then find $M$ so that when $x\ge M$, $\frac{(x+1)\arctan(x)}{22x+5}\ge\frac1{44}$. Then you can compare with
$$
\int_M^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{44\sqrt{x}}
$$

Comment: If I use the term "comparaison" I don't mean greater or less than but I mean I compare the nature of the integrals: convergent or divergent.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Ah, there's a linguistic difference here :) And, personally, I would encourage my students to use limit comparison rather than having to go through the next step of robjohn's argument to make it a standard comparison argument. But à chacun son goût. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it :)

Answer (score 2):

By the integral test, the convergence of given integral is equivalent to the convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)\arctan n}{(22n+5)\sqrt n}$$
Also notice that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{ \frac{(n+1)\arctan n}{(22n+5)\sqrt n} }{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}=\frac{\pi}{44}$$
Thus by the limit comparison test, since $\sum\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ diverges, given integral also diverges.